# JQuery mobile: Replace thumbnail with data element

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

In JQuery mobile listview, how can I replace the left-side thumbnail image with a data element?

Say I have a list of daily exercise tips.  Instead of an image to the left, I want to show the "Day" of the tip.  Like this:

4  Lift some weights --> 
3  Do some squats -->  
2  Do some pushups -->  
1  Stretch your muscles -->

Assume in the "tips" model, there's a field for "Day", just like there's a field for content. Day is a number.

So, instead of this current code (which works to put a img to the left)

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="d" >
  <div class="content-primary">
    <ul data-role="listview" >
      <% @all_challenges.each do |tip| %>
        <li><a href="#">
                <img src="/images/icondock/accept2.png" class="ui-li-icon">
                <h3><%= tip.outboundtitle %></h3>
            </a>
                <ul><!-- Second page with full tip -->
                    <li>
                        <br />
                        <p><%= tip.outgoing %></p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

I want to replace that  line with a data element: <%= tip.day %>

What I can't figure out is how to let JQuery Mobile let me keep that great 32X32 space to the left, but not expect an image there.  I want to put a big number (day) in there.

If I replace the img src line with <%= tip.day %> it just puts the number on **TOP** of the tip, and both are left justified.  Two lines.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just created a sample with hardcoded values.Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Main Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .day{
        margin-top: -15px;
        font-size:1.5em;
        color:red;
    }
    #list .ui-link-inherit{
        padding-left:30px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content"> 
    <ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#"><div class="day ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb">4</div>Lift some weights</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div class="day ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb">3</div>Do some squats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div class="day ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb">2</div>Do some pushups</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div class="day ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb">1</div>Stretch your muscles</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/5PPs4/

Let me know if that helps